# Как минифицировать .js и .sass в laravel.mix?

Tags: laravel, laravel5

Друзья, привет !
Нужна помощь, работаю с проектом на laravel 5 , стал вопрос как минифцировать скомпилированные файлы с помощью laravel.mix , чтобы при компиляции js and sass не просто скомпилировать в public/js а сразу отправлять его минифицированным ?

Помогите пожалуйста, либо какими то форумами или документацией подробной об этом, буду очень признателен, Спасибо !

Answer (score 2):

В `package.json` есть команда для использования в `prod` окружении с аналогичным названием, для сборки стилей и скриптов и их минификации. Она включена по умолчанию. Подразумевается, что вы будете при разработке использовать `dev` окружение (вы как раз сейчас в нем разрабатываете), после чего заливать проект на боевой сервер и там из консоли запускать билд для prod `npm run production` и скрипты и стили будут минифицированы. Минификация по идеологии Laravel происходит только в производственном режиме.

[Схожая проблема с Вашей](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47217153/how-does-minification-of-css-files-using-laravel-mix-work)

[Вот этот раздел документации](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/mix)